# Whitespace problems in OCaml

Tags: whitespace, ocaml

I'm trying to learn OCaml, and am reading the [Introduction to Objective Caml](http://files.metaprl.org/doc/ocaml-book.pdf)
I use OCamlWinPlus v1.9RC4 as my toploop.

When tryting to solve exercise 3.4 which is about programming Euclid's original GCD algorithm, I ran into a weird problem: It seems white-space is significant when typing in the program.

My first attempt was this:

```
let rec (%%) n m =
  if m = 0 then
    n
  else
    if n > m then
      (n-m) %% m
    else
      n %% (m-n);;
```

which gave the type:

```
val ( %% ) : int -> int -> 'a = <fun>
```

Hmm... not really what I expected, and sure enough `54 %% 24` gave an infinite loop.

After much mocking about, I tried putting the whole thing on one line like this:

```
let rec (%%) n m = if m = 0 then n else if n > m then (n-m) %% m else n %% (m-n);;
```

Which gave the type:

```
val ( %% ) : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Much better, and this one-liner also seems to work correctly.

I would like to know if anybody can explain this behavior?
I've tried putting parantheses in various places, but nothing seems to work.
Could it be a problem with the toploop?

I hope somebody can help me with this, since I'm uncomfortable with continuing to learn this language until I know what's going on.

**EDIT:**

I tried copy-pasting the showed code snippets back into OCamlWinPlus, and I got the exact same problematic result.

Details of my system:

- Windows XP, Home Edition, Version 2002, Service Pack 3
- OCaml version 3.11.0.
- OCamlWinPlus v1.9RC4

Comment: Weird problem indeed, both give `val ( %% ) : int -> int -> int = <fun>` on my system.

Comment: Weird indeed. Same here (both give the proper type).

Comment: yup; fine on my system too (in 3.12rc1, 3.11.2)

Comment: I copied your code from my browser, and pasted it directly to OCaml's toploop, and I get the correct results.

Comment: whitespace is not significant in ocaml

Answer (score 3):

The code you tested is *not* the code you're showing. Most probably, you tested a version without the `if m = 0` test, or with a different result calling the `%%` operator recursively. That would explain both the `'a` return type and the non-termination: `'a` inferred here means "abnormal computation".

For the link between `'a` and non-termination, see Andrew Koenig's article [An anecdote about ML type inference](http://www.usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/vhll/full_papers/koenig.a).

Comment: I tried copy-pasting the showed code snippets back into OCamlWinPlus and I got the exact same problematic result. Details of my system: Windows XP Home Edition, Version 2002, Service Pack 3. OCaml version 3.11.0. OCamlWinPlus v1.9RC4.

Comment: @Per: this doesn't make sense. I suppose you're sure that's exactly this code you tried. This seems completely irrational, and it calls for irrational solutions: try to reinstall OCaml (why not with a different version), then to use a different operating system (Unix-derived systems are more comfortable for OCaml programming anyway), then, if that still don't work, I suggest you burn your computer -- for the more environmentally-conscious, giving it away should be enough -- as a sacrifice to the God of Emergent Nondeterminism, and start from a different one.